# How to turn UTC+6 into local time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

i have a table with several timezones but just saved as string like "UTC+1" or "UTC-6" etc

how do i put that through the DateTime function to get what the time would be now in that zone

is it even possible?

am i close with this?:

```
$localtime = new DateTime("now", "UTC+6");
```

thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15626078/1203643 Feels like it should be that what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: setting a timezone by UTC offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276304/php-setting-a-timezone-by-utc-offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this trick, but looks like this question is already been asked and answered:

[php: setting a timezone by UTC offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276304/php-setting-a-timezone-by-utc-offset)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @vascowhite, I don't think I had comment permissions. I just got a notice that I received them when I logged in today.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `date_default_timezone_set` like so:

```
date_default_timezone_set(UTC+6 TIMZONE HERE);
```

Comment: No, they should most definitely not do that. Plus, it doesn't answer the question of how to convert dates to another timezone.