# Converting GMT from a JSON feed to Local Time in PHP

Tags: php, timestamp, iso8601, gmt

I get a JSON feed with GMT time in ISO 8601 format, and I wanted to display it changed to local time.

The script I have is below

```
$json = json_decode($response,true);

$output = "<ul>";
foreach($json['clients'] as $client){
    $output .= "<h4><p style=color:#FFFFFF;align=center>".$client['timestamp']." ".$date2."</h4>";

}
$output .= "</ul>";
```

What code can I insert into the foreach part to display each of the timestamps from the JSON feed in local time?

I am in Melbourne Australia so it will be +11 hours.

Thanks All

Rob

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15626078/5447994

Comment: Hi @VijayaSankarN sorry, didnt seem to work. I placed it after the Forelse statement and it only seemed to repeat the same time stamp in a different format. Did not add the 11 hours?

Comment: The second solution on the same page did work though. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the timestamp value. [Check This](https://eval.in/461929)

Comment: Hi @Uchiha it's ok. The past comment solved my issue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set your `timezone` using `date_default_timezone_set` like as

```
date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Melbourne");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s P',strtotime($date2));
```