# How to change GMT timezone to GMT+7 in gmdate PHP?

Tags: php

i'am still beginner in php. i have problem to get right time when using date_default_timezone_set().
so i try gmdate but i don't know how to add hours when get time using gmdate.
is there anyone know how to add hours or change GMT to GMT+7 in PHP?
please and thank you

Comment: The easiest way to handle dates is almost always to use PHP's `DateTime` class. Never add or subtract hours. Just change the timezone. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625834/how-to-convert-between-time-zones-in-php-using-the-datetime-class/15626078#15626078.

Comment: thank you, i will try it now.