# How do you get the "last modified" date from a file in the correct time zone?

Tags: php, html

So I am trying to get the Last Modified date of a file in PHP, I am using this:

```
$file = "my_file.txt";
$date = date("F j, Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file));
```

Now the problem is when I echo it, I do not get it in my timezone.
It comes up in UTC time, but I am in UTC-4 timezone.

(***e1:***) How do I get it to show my timezone, or even (***e2:***) display it in the timezone for whoever is viewing the webpage?

**Example 1:** Lets say I update the file at 1pm (UTC-4). Anyone looking at the webpage will see it displayed as 1pm (UTC-4) regardless of where they are located.

**Example 2:** Say I update the file at 1pm (UTC-4), and someone from the timezone UTC is looking at my webpage; they will see the time 5pm (UTC), because that's the time I uploaded it in their timezone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert between time zones in PHP using the DateTime class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625834/how-to-convert-between-time-zones-in-php-using-the-datetime-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the server time from PHP and store it in an HTML element. (There are other ways to pass the data, but this one is pretty easy to understand.) Here, I just used the `time()` function to grab the current time.  Your `filemtime` method should return a timestamp if you omit the formatting options.

Then, grab the timestamp from the `<div>` with JS.  Since the JS want milliseconds, multiply it by 1000.  Then use `toLocalString()` to offset it to the user's local time.

```
<div id="timeholder" data-time="<?php echo json_encode(time()); ?>"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date(document.getElementById('timeholder').dataset.time * 1000).toLocaleString();
    console.log(date);
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, updated.  And if you want the date formatted differently, you can pass options to `toLocaleString()`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: >keeping it in PHP?  I don't think so.  PHP only knows what time the server has.  You'll need to communicate with the user's browser to get their local offset.  Hence the JS.

Comment: How can I just take the current time, and - it 4 hours in php lmaoo

Comment: 4 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds = 14400 seconds.  Subtract 14400 from the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

### For Example 1:

Thanks to @thingEvery for doing the math on how much I needed to subtract from the current timestamp.

```
$filetime = date("U", filemtime($pfile));
$hoursToSubtract = 4;
$timeToSubtract = ($hoursToSubtract * 60 * 60);
    
$mytime = $filetime - $timeToSubtract;

# I needed to print it in two different formats,
# that's why I split it up
$time1 = date("F j, Y", $mytime);
$time2 = date("g:i A [e-4]", $mytime);
```